# Error LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, lnk2019

I've downloaded this C++ code from the SBIG website in order to control (take pictures and save them) the camera (model ST-401ME) which I purchased from them. I have a Matlab program which needs to call this so I'm trying to compile (with Visual Studio) this code with its headers and libraries into an executable. However, when I try I get the above mentioned error. Just to note I have added the files which contain the libraries to the directory path.

The exact wording of the output is this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CaptureImage, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>Linking...
1>csbigcam.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SBIGUnivDrvCommand@12 referenced in function "public: enum PAR_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGCam::SBIGUnivDrvCommand(short,void *,void *)" (?SBIGUnivDrvCommand@CSBIGCam@@QAE?AW4PAR_ERROR@@FPAX0@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffclos referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffprec referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffpky referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffuky referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffppr referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffcrim referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffinit referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::SaveFITS(char const *)" (?SaveFITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffphis referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::History2FITS(struct fitsfile *)" (?History2FITS@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PAUfitsfile@@@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffmrhd referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffgrec referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffghsp referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffghdn referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffgkyj referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffgkyd referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffgkys referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffgpxv referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffgipr referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>csbigimg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ffopen referenced in function "public: enum SBIG_FILE_ERROR __thiscall CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *)" (?ReadFITSImage@CSBIGImg@@QAE?AW4SBIG_FILE_ERROR@@PBD@Z)
1>I:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CaptureImage\Debug\CaptureImage.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://i:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CaptureImage\CaptureImage\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>CaptureImage - 20 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I think this has to do with linking the libraries. I never learned how to do that in Visual Studio, and It doesn't help that the class I took in college was 5 years ago so I barely remember anything.

Because of the length of the code I'll only poast the parts where the errors occur. If you want more of it (like the main) just let me know.

**Code:**

*csbigcam.cpp*

```
#include "lpardrv.h"
#include "sbigudrv.h"
#include "csbigcam.h"
#include "csbigimg.h"
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#ifndef INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE -1
#endif

#define VERSION_STR     "1.2"   /* version of this class */

/*

 Temperature Conversion Constants
 Defined in the SBIG Universal Driver Documentation

*/
#define T0      25.0
#define R0       3.0
#define DT_CCD  25.0
#define DT_AMB  45.0
#define RR_CCD   2.57
#define RR_AMB   7.791
#define RB_CCD  10.0
#define RB_AMB   3.0
#define MAX_AD  4096

.
.
.

PAR_ERROR CSBIGCam::GetFullFrame(int &nWidth, int &nHeight)
{
    GetCCDInfoResults0 gcir;
    GetCCDInfoParams gcip;
    unsigned short vertNBinning;
    unsigned short rm;

    // Get the image dimensions
    vertNBinning = m_uReadoutMode >> 8;
    if ( vertNBinning == 0 )
        vertNBinning = 1;
    rm = m_uReadoutMode & 0xFF;
    gcip.request = (m_eActiveCCD == CCD_IMAGING ? CCD_INFO_IMAGING : CCD_INFO_TRACKING);
    if ( SBIGUnivDrvCommand(CC_GET_CCD_INFO, &gcip, &gcir) != CE_NO_ERROR )
        return m_eLastError;
    if ( rm >= gcir.readoutModes )
        return CE_BAD_PARAMETER;
    nWidth = gcir.readoutInfo[rm].width;
    if ( rm >=3 && rm <= 5 )
        nHeight = gcir.readoutInfo[rm-3].height / vertNBinning;
    else
        nHeight = gcir.readoutInfo[rm].height / vertNBinning;
    return CE_NO_ERROR;
}

.
.
.
```

*csbigcam.h*

```
#ifndef _CSBIGCAM_
#define _CSBIGCAM_

#ifndef _PARDRV_
 #include "sbigudrv.h"
#endif

#ifndef _CSBIGIMG_
 #include "csbigimg.h"
#endif

#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef enum {RELAY_XPLUS, RELAY_XMINUS, RELAY_YPLUS, RELAY_YMINUS } CAMERA_RELAY;
typedef enum {SBDF_LIGHT_ONLY, SBDF_DARK_ONLY, SBDF_DARK_ALSO } SBIG_DARK_FRAME;
typedef enum {GS_IDLE, GS_DAWN, GS_EXPOSING_DARK, GS_DIGITIZING_DARK, GS_EXPOSING_LIGHT,
    GS_DIGITIZING_LIGHT, GS_DUSK } GRAB_STATE;

class CSBIGCam {
private:
    PAR_ERROR m_eLastError;
    PAR_COMMAND m_eLastCommand;
    short m_nDrvHandle;
    CAMERA_TYPE m_eCameraType;
    CCD_REQUEST m_eActiveCCD;
    double m_dExposureTime;
    unsigned short m_uReadoutMode;
    ABG_STATE7 m_eABGState;
    int m_nSubFrameLeft, m_nSubFrameTop, m_nSubFrameWidth, m_nSubFrameHeight;
    GRAB_STATE m_eGrabState;
    double m_dGrabPercent;
    CFW_MODEL_SELECT m_eCFWModel;
    CFW_ERROR m_eCFWError;
    struct {
        unsigned short vertNBinning, hBin, vBin;
        unsigned short rm;
        int left, top, width, height;
    } m_sGrabInfo;

public:
    // Constructors/Destructors
    CSBIGCam();
    CSBIGCam(OpenDeviceParams odp);
    CSBIGCam(SBIG_DEVICE_TYPE dev);
    ~CSBIGCam();
    void Init();

    // Error Reporting Routines
    PAR_ERROR GetError();
    string GetErrorString();
    string GetErrorString(PAR_ERROR err);
    PAR_COMMAND GetCommand();

    // Accessor Functions
    double GetExposureTime(void) { return m_dExposureTime; }
    void SetExposureTime(double exp) { m_dExposureTime = exp; }
    CCD_REQUEST GetActiveCCD(void) { return m_eActiveCCD; }
    void SetActiveCCD(CCD_REQUEST ccd) { m_eActiveCCD = ccd; }
    unsigned short GetReadoutMode(void) { return m_uReadoutMode; }
    void SetReadoutMode(unsigned short rm) { m_uReadoutMode = rm; }
    CAMERA_TYPE GetCameraType(void) { return m_eCameraType; }
    ABG_STATE7 GetABGState(void) { return m_eABGState; }
    void SetABGState(ABG_STATE7 abgState) { m_eABGState = abgState; }
    void SetSubFrame(int nLeft, int nTop, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    void GetSubFrame(int &nLeft, int &nTop, int &nWidth, int &nHeight);
    PAR_ERROR GetReadoutInfo(double &pixelWidth, double &pixelHeight, double &eGain);

    // Driver/Device Routines
    PAR_ERROR OpenDriver();
    PAR_ERROR CloseDriver();
    PAR_ERROR OpenDevice(OpenDeviceParams odp);
    PAR_ERROR CloseDevice();
    PAR_ERROR GetDriverInfo(DRIVER_REQUEST request, GetDriverInfoResults0 &gdir);

    // High-Level Exposure Related Commands
    PAR_ERROR GrabSetup(CSBIGImg *pImg, SBIG_DARK_FRAME dark);
    PAR_ERROR GrabMain(CSBIGImg *pImg, SBIG_DARK_FRAME dark);
    PAR_ERROR GrabImage(CSBIGImg *pImg, SBIG_DARK_FRAME dark);
    void GetGrabState(GRAB_STATE &grabState, double &percentComplete);

    // Low-Level Exposure Related Commands
    PAR_ERROR StartExposure(SHUTTER_COMMAND shutterState);
    PAR_ERROR EndExposure(void);
    PAR_ERROR IsExposureComplete(MY_LOGICAL &complete);
    PAR_ERROR StartReadout(StartReadoutParams srp);
    PAR_ERROR EndReadout(void);
    PAR_ERROR ReadoutLine(ReadoutLineParams rlp, MY_LOGICAL darkSubtract, unsigned short *dest);
    PAR_ERROR DumpLines(unsigned short noLines);

    //Temperature Related Commands
    PAR_ERROR GetCCDTemperature(double &ccdTemp);
    PAR_ERROR SetTemperatureRegulation(MY_LOGICAL enable, double setpoint);
    PAR_ERROR QueryTemperatureStatus(MY_LOGICAL &enabled, double &ccdTemp,
        double &setpointTemp, double &percentTE);

    // Control Related Commands
    PAR_ERROR ActivateRelay(CAMERA_RELAY relay, double time);
    PAR_ERROR IsRelayActive(CAMERA_RELAY relay, MY_LOGICAL &active);
    PAR_ERROR AOTipTilt(AOTipTiltParams attp);
    PAR_ERROR CFWCommand(CFWParams cfwp, CFWResults &cfwr);

    // General Purpose Commands
    PAR_ERROR EstablishLink(void);
    string GetCameraTypeString(void);
    PAR_ERROR GetFullFrame(int &nWidth, int &nHeight);
    PAR_ERROR GetFormattedCameraInfo(string &ciStr, MY_LOGICAL htmlFormat = TRUE);

    // Utility functions
    MY_LOGICAL CheckLink(void);
    unsigned short DegreesCToAD(double degC, MY_LOGICAL ccd = TRUE);
    double ADToDegreesC(unsigned short ad, MY_LOGICAL ccd = TRUE);

    //CFW Functions
    CFW_MODEL_SELECT GetCFWModel(void) { return m_eCFWModel; }
    PAR_ERROR SetCFWModel(CFW_MODEL_SELECT cfwModel, CFW_COM_PORT comPort = CFWPORT_COM1);
    PAR_ERROR SetCFWPosition(CFW_POSITION position);
    PAR_ERROR GetCFWPositionAndStatus(CFW_POSITION &position, CFW_STATUS &status);
    PAR_ERROR GetCFWMaxPosition(CFW_POSITION &position);
    CFW_ERROR GetCFWError(void) { return m_eCFWError; }
    string GetCFWErrorString(CFW_ERROR err);
    string GetCFWErrorString(void);

    // Allows access directly to driver
    PAR_ERROR SBIGUnivDrvCommand(short command, void *Params, void *Results);
};

#endif /* #ifndef _CSBIGCAM_ */
```

*csbigimg.ccp*

```
#include "lpardrv.h"
#include "csbigimg.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

/*
 Local Constants
*/
#if TARGET == ENV_MACOSX
    #define LONGLONG long long
#endif
#define FILE_VERSION    3       /* current header version written */
#define DATA_VERSION    1       /* current data version written */
#define HEADER_LEN      2048
#define VERSION_STR     "1.2"   /* version of this class */
static const char   *HEADER_KEYWORDS[] =
{
    "File_version = ",
    "Data_version = ",
    "Exposure = ",
    "Focal_length = ",
    "Aperture = ",
    "Response_factor = ",
    "Note = ",
    "Background = ",
    "Range = ",
    "Height = ",
    "Width = ",
    "Date = ",
    "Time = ",
    "Exposure_state = ",
    "Temperature = ",
    "Number_exposures = ",
    "Each_exposure = ",
    "History = ",
    "Observer = ",
    "X_pixel_size = ",
    "Y_pixel_size = ",
    "Pedestal = ",
    "E_gain = ",
    "User_1 = ",
    "User_2 = ",
    "User_3 = ",
    "User_4 = ",
    "Filter = ",
    "Readout_mode = ",
    "Track_time = ",
    "Sat_level = ",
    "End"
};
typedef enum
{
    HH_FILE_VERSION,
    HH_DATA_VERSION,
    HH_EXPOSURE,
    HH_FOCAL_LENGTH,
    HH_APERTURE,
    HH_RESPONSE_FACTOR,
    HH_NOTE,
    HH_BACKGROUND,
    HH_RANGE,
    HH_HEIGHT,
    HH_WIDTH,
    HH_DATE,
    HH_TIME,
    HH_EXPOSURE_STATE,
    HH_TEMPERATURE,
    HH_NUMBER_EXPOSURES,
    HH_EACH_EXPOSURE,
    HH_HISTORY,
    HH_OBSERVER,
    HH_X_PIXEL_SIZE,
    HH_Y_PIXEL_SIZE,
    HH_PEDESTAL,
    HH_E_GAIN,
    HH_USER_1,
    HH_USER_2,
    HH_USER_3,
    HH_USER_4,
    HH_FILTER,
    HH_READOUT_MODE,
    HH_TRACK_TIME,
    HH_SAT_LEVEL,
    HH_END
} SBIG_HEADER_HEADING;

.
.
.

#if INCLUDE_FITSIO
            /* save file in FITS format */
            res = SaveFITS(pFullPath);
#else

.
.
.

SBIG_FILE_ERROR CSBIGImg::History2FITS(fitsfile *fptr)
{
    int         status = 0;
    const char  *msg, *p;
    char        c, *cp = (char*)m_cHistory.c_str();
    int         index;
    MY_LOGICAL  first = TRUE;

    while (*cp) {
        c = *cp++;
        if ( (p=strchr(HISTORY_CHARS, c)) != NULL ) {
            index = (p - HISTORY_CHARS)/sizeof(const char);
            msg = HISTORY_PHRASES[index];
        } else if ( c == '0' )
            continue;
        else
            msg = "???";

        if ( first )
            fits_write_key(fptr, TSTRING, "SWMODIFY", (void *)m_cSoftware.c_str(), "", &status);
        first = FALSE;

        if (fits_write_history(fptr,msg,&status)) {
            return SBFE_FITS_HEADER_ERROR;
        }
    }
    return SBFE_NO_ERROR;
}

.
.
.

SBIG_FILE_ERROR CSBIGImg::ReadFITSImage(char const *pFullPath)
{
SBIG_FILE_ERROR err = SBFE_FORMAT_ERROR;
fitsfile *fptr;         /* FITS file pointer, defined in fitsio.h */
char card[FLEN_CARD];   /* Standard string lengths defined in fitsio.h */
int status = 0;         /* CFITSIO status value MUST be initialized to zero! */
int hdupos, nkeys, ii, jj;
int bitpix, naxis;
long naxes[2] = {1,1}, fpixel[2] = {1,1};
unsigned short *uip;
long l, l2;
double d;
char s[80];
MY_LOGICAL first = TRUE;
struct tm obs;

if (!fits_open_file(&fptr, pFullPath, READONLY, &status))
{
    do {        // Allow to break out
        // get and check the dimensions
        if ( fits_get_img_param(fptr, 2, &bitpix, &naxis, naxes, &status) ) break;
        if ( bitpix != 16 || naxis != 2 ) break;

        // allocate the buffer
        err = SBFE_MEMORY_ERROR;
        if ( !AllocateImageBuffer(naxes[1], naxes[0]) ) break;
        uip = GetImagePointer();

        // read the image data
        err = SBFE_READ_ERROR;
        if ( fits_read_pix(fptr, TUSHORT, fpixel, naxes[0]*naxes[1], NULL, uip, NULL, &status) ) break;

        // try and read the SBIG keys
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_OBJ], s, NULL, &status) )    SetFITSObject(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_SCOPE], s, NULL, &status) )  SetFITSTelescope(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_INST], s, NULL, &status) )   SetCameraModel(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_OBS], s, NULL, &status) )    SetObserver(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_DATEOBS], s, NULL, &status) ) {
                        if ( sscanf(s,"%4d-%2d-%2dT%2d.%2d.%2d", &obs.tm_year, &obs.tm_mon, &obs.tm_mday,
                                    &obs.tm_hour, &obs.tm_min, &obs.tm_sec) == 6 ) {
                            obs.tm_year -= 1900; obs.tm_mon -= 1;
                            memcpy(&m_sDecodedImageStartTime, &obs, sizeof(struct tm));
                        }
                    }
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_EXP], &d, NULL, &status) )   SetExposureTime(d);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_CCDT], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetCCDTemperature(d);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_PIXX], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetPixelWidth(d/1000.0);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_PIXY], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetPixelHeight(d/1000.0);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_BINX], &l, NULL, &status) &&
                         !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_BINY], &l2, NULL, &status) ) SetBinning((unsigned short)l, (unsigned short)l2);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_ORGX], &l, NULL, &status) &&
                         !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_ORGY], &l2, NULL, &status) ) SetSubFrame((unsigned short)l, (unsigned short)l2);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_EGAIN], &d, NULL, &status) )     SetEGain(d);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_FL], &d, NULL, &status) )    SetFocalLength(d/25.4);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_APTD], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetApertureDiameter(d/25.4);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_APTA], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetApertureArea(d/25.4/25.4);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_BLACK], &l, NULL, &status) ) SetBackground(l);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_WHITE], &l, NULL, &status) ) SetRange(l - GetBackground());
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_PED], &l, NULL, &status) )   SetPedestal((unsigned short)(l+100));
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_MAX], &l, NULL, &status) )   SetSaturationLevel((unsigned short)l);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_SWA],  s, NULL, &status) )   SetSoftware(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_FILT],  s, NULL, &status) )  SetFilter(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_SNAP], &l, NULL, &status) )  SetNumberExposures((unsigned short)l);
                                                                                            SetEachExposure(GetExposureTime()/l);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_lng(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_RES], &l, NULL, &status) )   SetReadoutMode((unsigned short)l);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_EXPST],  s, NULL, &status) && sscanf(s,"%lX", &l) == 1 ) SetExposureState((unsigned short)l);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_RESP], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetResponseFactor(d);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_str(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_NOTE],  s, NULL, &status) )      SetImageNote(s);
        status = 0; if ( !fits_read_key_dbl(fptr, FITS_KEYS[FK_TRAK], &d, NULL, &status) )  SetTrackExposure(d);
        status = 0;

        // read and filter out the parsed keywords
        fits_get_hdu_num(fptr, &hdupos);  /* Get the current HDU position */
        for (; !status; hdupos++)  /* Main loop through each extension */
        {
            fits_get_hdrspace(fptr, &nkeys, NULL, &status); /* get # of keywords */
            for (ii = 1; ii <= nkeys; ii++) { /* Read and print each keywords */
                if (fits_read_record(fptr, ii, card, &status)) break;
                for (jj=0; jj<FK_NEXT; jj++) {
                    l = strlen(FITS_KEYS[jj]);
                    if ( strncmp(card, FITS_KEYS[jj], l) == 0 ) break;
                }
                if ( jj == FK_NEXT ) {
                    if ( !first ) m_cAdditionalFITSKeys += "\r";
                    m_cAdditionalFITSKeys += card ;
                    first = FALSE;
                }
            }
            fits_movrel_hdu(fptr, 1, NULL, &status);  /* try to move to next HDU */
        }
        if (status == END_OF_FILE)  status = 0; /* Reset after normal error */
        if ( status ) break;            

        // got here so there was no error
        err = SBFE_NO_ERROR;
        m_nDefaultImageFormat = SBIF_FITS;
    } while ( FALSE );
    fits_close_file(fptr, &status);
}

if (err == SBFE_NO_ERROR && status)
    err = SBFE_FORMAT_ERROR;
if ( err != SBFE_NO_ERROR )
    DeleteImageData();
return(err);
}
#endif
```

*csbigimg.h*

```
#ifndef _CSBIGIMG_
    #define _CSBIGIMG_
/*
  Compile Time Options
*/
    #define INCLUDE_FITSIO  1       /* set to 1 to compile and link with FITSIO Library */

    #ifndef _LPARDRV_
        #include "lpardrv.h"
    #endif
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

    #if INCLUDE_FITSIO
        #include "fitsio.h"
    #endif  /* INCLUDE_FITSIO */

#ifndef PI
    #define PI  3.1415926535
#endif

/*
 Exposure State Field Defines
*/
    #define ES_ABG_MASK             0x0003
    #define ES_ABG_UNKNOWN          0x0000
    #define ES_ABG_LOW              0x0001
    #define ES_ABG_CLOCKED          0x0002
    #define ES_ABG_MID              0x0003

    #define ES_ABG_RATE_MASK        0x00C0
    #define ES_ABG_RATE_FIXED       0x0000
    #define ES_ABG_RATE_LOW         0x0040
    #define ES_ABG_RATE_MED         0x0080
    #define ES_ABG_RATE_HI          0x00C0

    #define ES_DCS_MASK             0x000c
    #define ES_DCS_UNKNOWN          0x0000
    #define ES_DCS_ENABLED          0x0004
    #define ES_DCS_DISABLED         0x0008

    #define ES_DCR_MASK             0x0030
    #define ES_DCR_UNKNOWN          0x0000
    #define ES_DCR_ENABLED          0x0010
    #define ES_DCR_DISABLED         0x0020

    #define ES_AUTOBIAS_MASK        0x0100
    #define ES_AUTOBIAS_ENABLED     0x0100
    #define ES_AUTOBIAS_DISABLED    0x0000

typedef enum { SBIF_COMPRESSED,
               SBIF_UNCOMPRESSED,
               SBIF_FITS,
               SBIF_DEFAULT } SBIG_IMAGE_FORMAT;
typedef enum
{
    SBFE_NO_ERROR,
    SBFE_OPEN_ERROR,
    SBRE_CLOSE_ERROR,
    SBFE_READ_ERROR,
    SBFE_WRITE_ERROR,
    SBFE_FORMAT_ERROR,
    SBFE_MEMORY_ERROR,
    SBFE_FITS_HEADER_ERROR,
    SBFE_WRONG_SIZE,
    SBFE_NEXT_ERROR
} SBIG_FILE_ERROR;

class CSBIGImg
{
/* */
private:
    int                 m_nHeight, m_nWidth;            // image size in pixels
    int                 m_nSubFrameTop, m_nSubFrameLeft;// for partial frames the top-left pixel
    unsigned short      *m_pImage;                      // pointer to image data
    double              m_dCCDTemperature;              // CCD Temp at start of exposure
    double              m_dExposureTime;                // Exposure time in seconds
    double              m_dTrackExposure;               // Exposure when tracking
    double              m_dEachExposure;                // Snapshot time in seconds
    double              m_dFocalLength;                 // Lens/Telescope Focal Length in inches
    double              m_dApertureArea;                // Lens/Telescope Aperture Are in Sq-Inches
    double              m_dResponseFactor;              // Magnitude Calibration Factor
    double              m_dPixelHeight, m_dPixelWidth;  // Pixel Dimensions in mm
    double              m_dEGain;                       // Electronic Gain, e-/ADU
    long                m_lBackground, m_lRange;        // Display Background and Range
    unsigned short      m_uNumberExposures;             // Number of exposures co-added
    unsigned short      m_uSaturationLevel;             // Pixels at this level are saturated
    unsigned short      m_uPedestal;                    // Image Pedestal
    unsigned short      m_uExposureState;               // Exposure State
    unsigned short      m_uReadoutMode;                 // Camera Readout Mode use to acquire image
    unsigned short      m_uHorizontalBinning;           // Binning used in X
    unsigned short      m_uVerticalBinning;             // Binning used in Y
    string              m_cImageNote;                   // Note attached to image
    string              m_cObserver;                    // Observer name
    string              m_cHistory;                     // Image History string of modification chars
    string              m_cFilter;                      // Filter name imaged through
    string              m_cSoftware;                    // Software App Name and Version
    string              m_cCameraModel;                 // Model of camera used to acquire image
    int                 m_isCompressed;                 // clc
    MY_LOGICAL          m_bImageModified;               // True when modified and not saved
    SBIG_IMAGE_FORMAT   m_nDefaultImageFormat;          // default image format for Saves
    struct tm           m_sDecodedImageStartTime;       // Decoded time light exposure started
    MY_LOGICAL          m_bImageCanClose;               // TRUE when image can be closed, FALSE if owned by
                                                        //  a CSBIGCam object and acquiring data

/* */
public:
    /* Constructors/Destructor */
    CSBIGImg(void);
    CSBIGImg(int height, int width);
    ~               CSBIGImg(void);

    void            Init(void);
    void            DeleteImageData(void);
.
.
.
    /* More Accessor Functions */
    void            SetImageStartTime(void);
    void            SetImageStartTime(time_t startTime);
    void            SetImageStartTime(int mon, int dd, int yy, int hr, int min, int sec);
    void            SetImageStartTime(struct tm *pStartTime);
    void            SetSubFrame(int nLeft, int nTop);
    void            GetSubFrame(int &nLeft, int &nTop);
    void            SetBinning(unsigned short nHoriz, unsigned short nVert);
    void            GetBinning(unsigned short &nHoriz, unsigned short &nVert);
    void            AddHistory(string str);

    /* File IO Routines */
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR SaveImage(const char *pFullPath, SBIG_IMAGE_FORMAT fmt = SBIF_DEFAULT);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR OpenImage(const char *pFullPath);

    /* Utility Functions */
    MY_LOGICAL      AllocateImageBuffer(int height, int width);
    void            CreateSBIGHeader(char *pHeader, MY_LOGICAL isCompressed);
    MY_LOGICAL      ParseHeader(char *pHeader, MY_LOGICAL &isCompressed);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR SaveCompressedImage(const char *pFullPath, char *pHeader);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR ReadCompressedImage(FILE *fh);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR SaveUncompressedImage(const char *pFullPath, char *pHeader);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR ReadUncompressedImage(FILE *fh);    
    int             CompressSBIGData(unsigned char *pCmpData, int imgRow);
    void            IntelCopyBytes(unsigned char *pRevData, int imgRow);
    void            AutoBackgroundAndRange(void);
    string          GetFileErrorString(SBIG_FILE_ERROR err);
    unsigned short  GetAveragePixelValue(void);
    unsigned short  GetAveragePixelValue(int left, int top, int width, int height);
    void            GetFormattedImageInfo(string &iiStr, MY_LOGICAL htmlFormat = TRUE);

    /* Image Processing Funcions */
    void            VerticalFlip(void);
    void            HorizontalFlip(void);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR DarkSubtract(CSBIGImg *pImg);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR FlatField(CSBIGImg *pImg);

    /* Color Image Processing */
    void            RemoveBayerColor(void);

#if INCLUDE_FITSIO
private:
    string          m_cFITSObject;                      // Name of object in FITS header
    string          m_cFITSTelescope;                   // Name of telescope in FITS header
    double          m_dApertureDiameter;     // Diameter of telescope
    string          m_cAdditionalFITSKeys;              // additional FITS keywords

public:
    /* FITS Accessor functions */
    void        SetFITSObject(string str)       { m_cFITSObject = str; }
    string      GetFITSObject(void)             { return m_cFITSObject;}
    void        SetFITSTelescope(string str)    { m_cFITSTelescope = str; }
    string      GetFITSTelescope(void)          { return m_cFITSTelescope;}
    void        SetApertureDiameter(double ap)  { m_dApertureDiameter = ap; }
    double      GetApertureDiameter(void)       { return m_dApertureDiameter; }
    void        SetAdditionalFITSKeys(string str) { m_cAdditionalFITSKeys = str; }
    string      GetAdditionalFITSKeys(void)     { return m_cAdditionalFITSKeys; }

    /* FITS file format utilities */
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR SaveFITS(const char *pFullPath);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR History2FITS(fitsfile *fptr);
    SBIG_FILE_ERROR ReadFITSImage(const char *pFullPath);
#endif
};

#endif /* #ifndef _CSBIGIMG_ */
```

Comment: As you guessed, it does have to do with linking in your libraries.  There are certainly many tutorials on how to do so in VS out there.

Comment: Add the library or libraries that are in the package you're linking to to the C++ project's "Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies" properties. This needs to be done *in addition* to adding the directories they're in to the library search path.

Comment: All the possible reasons for [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx)<=

Comment: Here listed common reasons [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) . It helped me to resolve the problem at least.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this error after adding the include files and linking the library. It was because the lib was built with non-unicode and my application was unicode. Matching them fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

When you have everything #included, an unresolved external symbol is often a missing * or & in the declaration or definition of a function.